# ¿Es posible tener una clave primaria compuesta con asociaciones a otras tables donde uno de los valores puede ser null?

Tags: mysql, sql

En un ejercicio se plantean estas tablas para desarrollar en mysql:

```
MINORISTA (@nro_minorista, nombre_minorista, dirección_minorista)
MAYORISTA(@nro_mayorista, nombre_mayorista, dirección_mayorista)
PRODUCTO(@nro_producto, precio)
PEDIDOS(@nro_minorista,@nro_mayorista,@nro_producto,cantidad)
```

Considerando que un pedido solo puede ser realizado o bien por un mayorista, o bien por un minorista, en caso de establecer claves foráneas para nro_minorista y nro_mayorista que vinculen sus valores entre la tabla PEDIDOS y las correspondientes MINORISTA y MAYORISTA, ¿es posible tener una clave primaria compuesta en pedidos como se indica, cuando uno de los valores va a ser NULL? Mi impresión inicial es que no, pero tal vez me estoy perdiendo de algo.

```
CREATE TABLE `mayorista` (
  `nro_mayorista` int NOT NULL,
  `direccion_mayorista` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ciudad` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`nro_mayorista`)

CREATE TABLE `minorista` (
  `nro_minorista` int NOT NULL,
  `nombre_minorista` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dirección_minorista` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ciudad` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`nro_minorista`)

CREATE TABLE `producto` (
  `nro_producto` int NOT NULL,
  `descuento` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `peso` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `precio` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`nro_producto`)

CREATE TABLE `pedidos` (
  `nro_minorista` INT NOT NULL,
  `nro_mayorista` INT NOT NULL,
  `nro_producto` INT NOT NULL,
  `cantidad` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`nro_minorista`, `nro_mayorista`, `nro_producto`),
  INDEX `fk_may_idx` (`nro_mayorista` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_prod_idx` (`nro_producto` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_may`
    FOREIGN KEY (`nro_mayorista`)
    REFERENCES `mayorista` (`nro_mayorista`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_min`
    FOREIGN KEY (`nro_minorista`)
    REFERENCES `minorista` (`nro_minorista`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_prod`
    FOREIGN KEY (`nro_producto`)
    REFERENCES `producto` (`nro_producto`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Comment: Es posible? Todo es posible. Te conviene? En mi opinión, no. Las relaciones entre las tablas modelan relaciones en el mundo real. El hecho que la tabla `Pedido` tenga dos llaves foráneas que **dependen** del *tipo de comprador*, me está diciendo *Un sólo pedido **podría** tener dos posibles compradores*. En el mundo real, eso no existe. Minorista y Mayorista son **tipos** de compradores, y deberían ir en su propio catálogo. Este `IDTipoComprador` deberá ir en `dbo.Comprador`. De esta manera, la tabla `Pedido` sólo llevará un `IDComprador`.

Comment: @Arriel perfecto! en realidad, después llegué a la conclusión de que el enunciado del ejercicio estaba incompleto, y que en realidad se estaban registrando los pedidos de los minoristas a los mayoristas, lo que sí tiene sentido en el mundo real... pero de cualquier manera quería sacarme la duda de si era posible hacer algo así. gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no puedes. La clave ajena, FK, te impide registrar ningún dato que no exista en la tabla referenciada. Y la clave principal, PK, de la tabla referenciada te impide registrar nulos.

Independientemente de alguna errata que tienes en la creación de las tablas fácilmente subsanable: te falta algún campo y no cierras el `);` en los `CREATE TABLE`; tienes una forma mucho más sencilla de conseguir lo que buscas.

Si te fijas, las tablas de mayoristas y minoristas son idénticas, tienen los mismos campos. No implementan ningún tipo de especialización, por lo que podrías fusionarlas en una tabla `empresas` que ya podrías referenciar con tu FK sin que te importe si es de un tipo u otro.

Para diferenciar mayoristas de minoristas en esa tabla `empresas` puedes utilizar un campo booleano.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios para completar lo mejor posible la respuesta.

Comment: Perfecto. Sí, me parece que lo más lógico sería unir mayoristas y minoristas en una tabla, y agregar una columna que indique a cuál categoría pertenecen.. gracias!